# Numbers if cell is equal to X or Y

Tags: numbers

Is it possible to test a cell using `IF` against multiple strings? So for example, I want the function to output `Fruit` in cell A2 if cell A1 contains the string `Apple` or `Orange`. I can only come up with this in cell A2:

```
IF(A1 = "Apple"|"Orange", "Fruit", "Not a fruit")
```

This results in an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is thankfully quite easy. You can achieve what you want using the `OR` function in Numbers (this function is also found on Microsoft Excel):

```
IF(OR(A1 = "Apple", A1 = "Orange"), "Fruit", "Not a fruit")
```

The argument for the `IF` function here is `OR(A1 = "Apple", A1 = "Orange")`. This `OR` function tests whether any of the arguments are correct; if they are, it returns `TRUE`. If none of them are correct, it returns `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2):

There is also this version :

```
IF(A1="Apple","Fruit",IF(A1="Orange","Fruit","Not a fruit"))
```

Which does not need OR() at all...

And this is one way of avoiding OR() and IF() using index and match...
Cell B2 shows the function entered in cell B1.

[image]